# clusters are not joining after x-pack configuration in elasticsearch 6.5.4

Tags: elasticsearch

I am not able to start elasticsearch 6.5.4 cluster after adding these xpack configurations to the yaml:

steps followed to configure xpack:

A. 
    xpack.security.enabled to true in elasticsearch.yml file.

B. generated certificate and private key using elasticsearch-certutil cert and copied it to other nodes.

C. enabled these in elasticsearch.yml on all the nodes, and started the nodes

```
xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled: true 
xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode: certificate 
xpack.security.transport.ssl.keystore.path: elastic-certificates.p12 
xpack.security.transport.ssl.truststore.path: elastic-certificates.p12 
xpack.license.self_generated.type: trial 

The two clusters are throwing below errors and are not able to join each other. Also if the elasticsearch node gets started and we do a basic curl it says authentication failure.

Please find the log below:

[cluster:monitor/nodes/stats[n]]
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSecurityException: missing authentication token for action [cluster:monitor/nodes/stats[n]]
at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.security.support.Exceptions.authenticationError(Exceptions.java:18) ~[?:?]
at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.security.authc.DefaultAuthenticationFailureHandler.createAuthenticationError(DefaultAuthenticationFailureHandler.java:161) ~[?:?]
at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.security.authc.DefaultAuthenticationFailureHandler.missingToken(DefaultAuthenticationFailureHandler.java:116) ~[?:?]
at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.AuthenticationService$AuditableTransportRequest.anonymousAccessDenied(AuthenticationService.java:517) ~[?:?]
at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.AuthenticationService$Authenticator.lambda$handleNullToken$17(AuthenticationService.java:342) ~[?:?]
at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.AuthenticationService$Authenticator.handleNullToken(AuthenticationService.java:347) ~[?:?]
at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.AuthenticationService$Authenticator.consumeToken(AuthenticationService.java:259) ~[?:?]
at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.AuthenticationService$Authenticator.lambda$extractToken$7(AuthenticationService.java:230) ~[?:?]
at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.AuthenticationService$Authenticator.extractToken(AuthenticationService.java:248) ~[?:?]
at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.AuthenticationService$Authenticator.lambda$authenticateAsync$0(AuthenticationService.java:182) ~[?:?]
at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionListener$1.onResponse(ActionListener.java:60) ~[elasticsearch-6.5.4.jar:6.5.4]
at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.TokenService.getAndValidateToken(TokenService.java:310) ~[?:?]
at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.AuthenticationService$Authenticator.lambda$authenticateAsync$2(AuthenticationService.java:178) ~[?:?]
at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.AuthenticationService$Authenticator.lambda$lookForExistingAuthentication$4(AuthenticationService.java:209) ~[?:?]
at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.AuthenticationService$Authenticator.lookForExistingAuthentication(AuthenticationService.java:220) ~[?:?]
at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.AuthenticationService$Authenticator.authenticateAsync(AuthenticationService.java:174) ~[?:?]
at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.AuthenticationService$Authenticator.access$000(AuthenticationService.java:134) ~[?:?]
at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.AuthenticationService.authenticate(AuthenticationService.java:104) ~[?:?]
at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.transport.ServerTransportFilter$NodeProfile.inbound(ServerTransportFilter.java:130) ~[?:?]
at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.transport.SecurityServerTransportInterceptor$ProfileSecuredRequestHandler.messageReceived(SecurityServerTransportInterceptor.java:307) ~[?:?]
at org.elasticsearch.transport.RequestHandlerRegistry.processMessageReceived(RequestHandlerRegistry.java:66) ~[elasticsearch-6.5.4.jar:6.5.4]
at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport$RequestHandler.doRun(TcpTransport.java:1350) ~[elasticsearch-6.5.4.jar:6.5.4]
at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingAbstractRunnable.doRun(ThreadContext.java:723) ~[elasticsearch-6.5.4.jar:6.5.4]
at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37) ~[elasticsearch-6.5.4.jar:6.5.4]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:1.8.0_242]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_242]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_242]
[2020-05-05T10:20:06,396][DEBUG][o.e.a.a.i.s.TransportIndicesStatsAction] [node-1] failed to execute [indices:monitor/stats] on node [S2HO0QXTQEGAVMYKt77uEA]
org.elasticsearch.transport.RemoteTransportException: [node-2][10.234.175.86:9300][indices:monitor/stats[n]]
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSecurityException: missing authentication token for action [indices:monitor/stats[n]]
at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.security.support.Exceptions.authenticationError(Exceptions.java:18) ~[?:?]
at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.security.authc.DefaultAuthenticationFailureHandler.createAuthenticationError(DefaultAuthenticationFailureHandler.java:161) ~[?:?]
at org.elasticsearch.xpack.core.security.authc.DefaultAuthenticationFailureHandler.missingToken(DefaultAuthenticationFailureHandler.java:116) ~[?:?]
at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.AuthenticationService$AuditableTransportRequest.anonymousAccessDenied(AuthenticationService.java:517) ~[?:?]
at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.AuthenticationService$Authenticator.lambda$handleNullToken$17(AuthenticationService.java:342) ~[?:?]
at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.AuthenticationService$Authenticator.handleNullToken(AuthenticationService.java:347) ~[?:?]
at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.AuthenticationService$Authenticator.consumeToken(AuthenticationService.java:259) ~[?:?]
at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.AuthenticationService$Authenticator.lambda$extractToken$7(AuthenticationService.java:230) ~[?:?]
at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.AuthenticationService$Authenticator.extractToken(AuthenticationService.java:248) ~[?:?]
at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.AuthenticationService$Authenticator.lambda$authenticateAsync$2(AuthenticationService.java:178) ~[?:?]
at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.AuthenticationService$Authenticator.lambda$lookForExistingAuthentication$4(AuthenticationService.java:209) ~[?:?]
at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.AuthenticationService$Authenticator.lookForExistingAuthentication(AuthenticationService.java:220) ~[?:?]
at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.AuthenticationService$Authenticator.authenticateAsync(AuthenticationService.java:174) ~[?:?]
at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.AuthenticationService$Authenticator.access$000(AuthenticationService.java:134) ~[?:?]
at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.AuthenticationService.authenticate(AuthenticationService.java:104) ~[?:?]
at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.transport.ServerTransportFilter$NodeProfile.inbound(ServerTransportFilter.java:130) ~[?:?]
at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.transport.SecurityServerTransportInterceptor$ProfileSecuredRequestHandler.messageReceived(SecurityServerTransportInterceptor.java:307) ~[?:?]
at org.elasticsearch.transport.RequestHandlerRegistry.processMessageReceived(RequestHandlerRegistry.java:66) ~[elasticsearch-6.5.4.jar:6.5.4]
at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport$RequestHandler.doRun(TcpTransport.java:1350) ~[elasticsearch-6.5.4.jar:6.5.4]
```

I have 3 node cluster but  they didnt join the cluster after configuring the xpack also wen trying to get index using the curl command it comes out to be unauthorized.

Comment: It seems you're missing `xpack.security.enabled: true`

Comment: @Val: it is there in configuration I have missed that out in question.

Comment: Ok, can you enumerate all the steps you went through to enable XPack, please?

Comment: sure. 1. xpack.security.enabled to  true in elasticsearch.yml file. 2. generated certificate and private key using elasticsearch-certutil cert and copied it to other  nodes. 3. xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled: true
xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode: certificate
xpack.security.transport.ssl.keystore.path: elastic-certificates.p12
xpack.security.transport.ssl.truststore.path: elastic-certificates.p12
xpack.license.self_generated.type: trial   enabled these in elasticsearch.yml on all the nodes, and started the nodes

Comment: @Val : please guide me through the soultion.